# How to add space between 2 images, which are below a block of text?

Tags: html, css

How would I add space between 2 images using html and css? This question was answered in another stackoverflow thread, but I wasn't able to apply that solution to mine because I couldn't understand it.

The main problem might be in the css, because I know that margin is outer space and padding is inner space, so I thought using those I might be able to create space using margin and padding, but *I am not using them properly*, I think.

Here's what I have:

HTML

```
<p> This paragraph is just where I put lots of unnecessary info about a tree and a house. </p>

<div id = "images"> 

<img src = "tree.png" alt = "Tree picture" width = "100" height = "100">
<img src = "house.png" alt = "House picture" width = "100" height = "100">

</div>
```

CSS

```
#images {
    margin:50px;
    padding:50px;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: I wanted a 50 pixel space between the 2 images, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target the actual images themselves to put spacing around them instead of the div that is outside of them.

```css
#images img {
    margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p>This paragraph is just where I put lots of unnecessary info about a tree and a house.</p>

<div id="images">
  <img src="tree.png" alt="Tree picture" width="100" height="100">
  <img src="house.png" alt="House picture" width="100" height="100">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way. Although, it is probably better to provide an identifier like ID and then set the css to the id.

```css
img
{
    padding:25px;
}
```

```html
<p> This paragraph is just where I put lots of unnecessary info about a tree and a house. </p>

<div id = "images"> 

<img src = "tree.png" alt = "Tree picture" width = "100" height = "100" >
<img src = "house.png" alt = "House picture" width = "100" height = "100">

</div>
```

Comment: It will, the img is referring to the HTML tag, it would be safer to use an ID or class so that another IMG tag will not be effected.

Comment: Yes, I created an ID which was "images". Thanks, Matt!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add this to your CSS, your code wasn't working because you were applying the CSS to the div and not the individual elements. An effective way would be to add a class(example, class="ex-image") to the img elements and then using that selector to apply changes.

```
img{
  margin: 25px;
}
```